# Como pegar cordenadas pela URL e montar um array especifico para a API do Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

estou tentando montar um mapa do google maps com alguns pins, onde as cordenadas serão passadas pela URL.

Porem eu preciso passar um array como este para a API:

```
var locations = [
  ['First Place', -37.808204, 144.855579],
  ['Second Place', -37.675648, 145.026125],
  ['Third Place', -37.816935, 144.966877]
];
```

No meu código eu consegui pegar os parâmetros e montar um array, mas não está parecido com o que preciso e não estou sabendo como melhorar.
Este é o código que eu montei até o momento:

```
var query = location.search.slice(1);
var places = query.split('&');
var locations = [];
places.forEach(function (place) {
    var chaveValor = place.split('=');
    var local = chaveValor[0];
    var cordenadas = chaveValor[1].split(",");
    locations[local] = cordenadas;
});

console.log(locations);
```

supondo que a url seja:

```
https://localhost/GoogleMaps/index.html?First-Place=-37.808204,144.855579&Second-Place-Teste=-37.675648,145.026125
```

Está retornando o seguinte:

```
[First-Place: ["-37.808204", "144.855579"], Second-Place-Teste: ["-37.675648", "145.026125"]]
```

Muito obrigado pelos que puderem ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o segundo argumento do `forEach` que retorna o índice da array para montar a nova array:

```
places.forEach(function (place, i) {
                                ↑
                             índice
```

E coloque o argumento (no caso, representado pela variável `i`) no lugar de `local` em:

```
locations[i] = cordenadas;
```

E adicione mais uma linha usando `.unshift` para adicionar a variável `local` como primeiro valor de cada array:

```
locations[i].unshift(local);
```

Ficará assim:

```
var query = location.search.slice(1);

var places = query.split('&');
var locations = [];
places.forEach(function (place, i) {
    var chaveValor = place.split('=');
    var local = chaveValor[0];
    var cordenadas = chaveValor[1].split(",");
    locations[i] = cordenadas;
    locations[i].unshift(local);
});

console.log(locations);
```

O retorno disso será:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso você queira que os valores das coordenadas sejam armazenadas em valor numério (não string), você pode converter usando `parseFloat()` dentro de um `.map()`. Basta alterar a linha:

```
locations[i] = cordenadas;
```

Por:

```
locations[i] = cordenadas.map( function(v){ return parseFloat(v); });
```

O resultado agora será:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, resolveu o meu problema.

Comment: Blz... acrescentei mais umas informações no final da resposta. Abs!